# Problem using Linq to join tables in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I used to have a straight up controller returning a view like this

```
return View(db.Stuff.ToList());
```

This works fine. I started laborating a bit and found that this:

```
var items = from g in db.Stuff
            select g;
return View(items);
```

...also works fine. However, as I try to join with another table :

```
var items = from g in db.Stuff
            join ug in db.OtherStuff on g.Id equals ug.StuffId
            where !ug.UserId.Equals(1)
            select g;
return View(items);
```

I get an error in the view saying:

*Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.*

Why is this? Another odd thing is that if I comment out the where clause, it seams to work again (work as in not throw an exception)

Comment: What is the type of `OtherStuff.UserId`?

Comment: Well, its a Guid/uniqueidentifier. I edited the question so it's alitlle bit less wierd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your where clause to this:

```
where ug.UserId != 1
```

Comment: Hm, well actually the userId is a Guid. I was not thinking that would make any diffrence... sorry about that. `where ug.UserId != new Guid()` works fine. **However** what I'm ultimatly am trying to achieve is to match `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey` and when I put `where ug.UserId = mu.ProviderUserKey` I do get the original error again...
**edit**: putting the ProviderUserKey in a Guid-variable first works tho. Thanks!